# Simple custom function using tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

```
def custum_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  
  d = y_pred - y_true
  d = np.abs(d)
  
  mean_ = np.mean(d)

  return mean_
```

This is my code and I got this error:

```
TypeError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "<ipython-input-105-c0cd30b49d79>", line 3, in custum_loss  *
        d = y_pred - y_true

TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Sub' Op has type int64 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks

Comment: What type is `y_true`? Specifically the dtype.

Answer (score 0):

`y_pred` has dtype `float32` and `y_true` `int64`, so you will need to convert `y_true` to float so that Numpy doesn't complain about the types when subtracting the arrays.

```py
d = y_pred - y_true.astype(np.float32)
```

Also, note that the loss you are implementing is the [Mean Absolute Error](https://keras.io/api/losses/regression_losses/#meanabsoluteerror-class) loss, which is already a part of keras. So unless you want to implement a more complex loss, and this is just some test, I would advise you use the keras loss, to avoid potential errors, and because the Keras code is likely optimised for speed.